# Does time-independent eigenbasis vectors (Heisenberg's picture) obey completion property?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

As far as I understood, In Heisenberg's picture, eigen vectors are time independent and Schrodinger's, eigen vectors are time dependent, also they are equivalent. Let $${\lvert q(t) \rangle}_S=e^{-i\hat Ht/\hbar }{\lvert q \rangle}_H$$ be the relation between Heisenberg's and Schrodinger's eigen state basis vectors. Also the completeness property is defined as $$\int_{\mathbf -\infty}^\infty {\lvert q(t) \rangle}_S {\langle q(t)\lvert}_S dq=1 .$$ My question is

> 1. Wheather the time-independent eigen basis vector (Heisenberg's view) follow this completeness property?$$\int_{\mathbf -\infty}^\infty {\lvert q(t) \rangle}_H {\langle q(t)\lvert}_H dq=1 .$$
>      If yes
> 2. How can we prove that completeness of Schrodinger's eigen state basis vectors equivalent to completeness Heisenberg's eigen state basis vectors.
>      That is, How can we prove,
>      $$\int_{\mathbf -\infty}^\infty {\lvert q(t) \rangle}_S {\langle q(t)\lvert}_S dq=1 \implies \int_{\mathbf -\infty}^\infty {\lvert q(t) \rangle}_H {\langle q(t)\lvert}_H dq=1$$

I attempted it by writing $$\int_{\mathbf -\infty}^\infty {\lvert q(t) \rangle}_S {\langle q(t)\lvert}_S dq=1 \implies \int_{\mathbf -\infty}^\infty e^{-i\hat Ht/\hbar }{\lvert q(t) \rangle}_H {\langle q(t)\lvert}_H e^{i\hat Ht/\hbar } dq=1 $$ and I was not able to eliminate the unitary operator. Can someone help me to proceed.

Comment: Multiply by $e^{iHt/\hbar}$ on the left and $e^{-iHt/\hbar}$ on the right and you will get what you want.

Comment: How can we include a position dependent quantity in the integral? Hamiltonian operator depends on the the position operator too. Thus it may affect the integral.

Comment: @walber97 no, it doesn't. $q$ here is simply a label for the basis states. $H$ is a basis independent object (even if it is often convenient to represent it in the position basis)

Comment: I am sorry that I still have confusion with this. $\hat H $ is depends on position operator. Thus action of position operator on position eigen vector will change the eigen value and thus the integrand. Is it like that?